# What beans can I use to make refried beans?

Tags: mexican-cuisine

Refried beans are traditionally made with pinto beans. However, I'm having trouble finding them; what other beans can I use to make refried beans?

Comment: Pinto and black beans are the ones I've seen used most commonly in Mexico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have made refried beans out of pinto, small red, black, and even navy beans. I almost tried using kidney beans once but it seemed wasteful.

They were all different in texture but they were all good. Black beans, for example, have a much more fibrous skin so the refried beans are not as smooth- I actually prefer it to the homogeneous pinto mash. Obviously their color is also more interesting.

There are a lot of different bean varieties and I don't know what is available to you. In general I would say to just try whatever you have- it will probably taste good even if it isn't exactly like pintos.

Comment: `I almost tried using kidney beans once but it seemed wasteful.` Question: why would it be wasteful -- is there some particular dish you use them for? Just curious about good uses for kidney beans.